# Redirect to URL if x number of days passed

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, conditional-tags, date-time, wp-redirect

Let's say I have this URL: **www.example.com/myCPT/post**, here I want to check if 3 days has passed since the post was created to redirect to **www.example.com/myCPT/post/stats**.

In this 3 days time frame the user should not be able to access **www.example.com/myCPT/post/stats**.

But this needs to be dynamic, every time a post is created to check for it's URL and add a 3 days time till this URL will be accessible **www.example.com/myCPT/post/stats**

For example I will have post1, post2, post3 and so on and every time the post will be created to add a 3 days time frame till the **"/post/stats"** will be available.

Also I need the same for **"/post/comments"** : this address should be available after 3 days, and if someone try to access before should be redirected to post url: **"/post"**

I did some research and I found this:

- `wp_redirect( $location, $status );` for redirection
- `<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>` and `<?php echo get_the_time(); ?>` for gettin the date/time of the post

Found a snippet which might be helpful :

```
if ( time() - strtotime( $posts[0]->post_date_gmt ) > ( 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) {
    // DO SOMETHING 
}
return $posts;
}
```

Later Edit :

The `"/stats"` and `"/comments"` endpoints are built like this :

```
function wpa121567_rewrite_endpoints(){

  add_rewrite_endpoint( 'stats', EP_PERMALINK );

}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa121567_rewrite_endpoints' );
```

Any suggestions on how can I achieve this?

Comment: "/stats" it's the same post but with an addition variable, and yes the url is created via an endpoint. I've updated my question with how "/stats" is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect after 3 days gone after publication, hook into `template_redirect`, check if is a singular cpt view, check the date and compare to current time and redirect if needed.

In the 3 days time frame, check if stats is is the query vars and if so redirect to post page.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'check_the_date_for_stats');

function check_the_date_for_stats() {
  if ( is_singular('myCPT ') ) { // adjust myCPT with your real cpt name
    $pl = get_permalink( get_queried_object() ); // permalink
    $is_stats = array_key_exists( 'stats', $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query ); // is stats?
    $is_cm = array_key_exists( 'comments', $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query ); // is comments?
    $ts = mysql2date('Ymd', get_queried_object()->post_date_gmt ); // post day
    $gone = ($ts + 3) < gmdate('Ymd'); // more than 3 days gone?
    if ( $gone && ( ! $is_stats && ! $is_cm ) ) {
       // more than 3 days gone and not is stats => redirect to stats
       wp_redirect( trailingslashit($pl) . '/stats' );
       exit();
    } elseif( ! $gone && ( $is_stats || $is_cm ) ) {
       // we are in 3 days frame and trying to access to stats => redirect to post
       wp_redirect( $pl );
       exit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, but is not working, what I mean by this is that when I access **www.mywebsite.com/cpt/post** it loads very very slow and after I get this: **This webpage has a redirect loop** and the URL in the browser is looking like this : **www.mywebsite.com/cpt/post//stats**. This should not  redirect me to "/stats" it should be the other way around when I'm trying to access "/stats" to redirect me to "/post".

Comment: Now I'm not getting the error anymore, but it still redirects me to "/stats" and it should redirect me after 3 days. Also when I'm trying to access "/stats"  before 3 days has passed it should redirect me to the "/post"

Comment: I've did this, but still when I'm accessing **/post** it redirects me **/stats** and I want to be redirected to **/stats** if 3 days has passed.

Comment: P.S. for "3 days has gone" I intend that if the post was published on day 10, it redirects to `'/stats'` starting form day 14. @Alecs

Comment: Yes, You're right ! my mistake, the post was older than 3 days. Thank you very much! And one more question, is it possible to add another variable to check for ? because I want to check also for another endpoint called "/comments" so that after 3 days user can access the "/comments".

Comment: No, It should be accessible after 3 days